# How to finish my http call to my REST API?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

I am using ionic with a Node Server where I have implemented a REST API, but I am having a issue: when i execute several times a update query in my frontend, the server just execute 6 requests and then stop functioning.

In Ionic App (FrontEnd) I have this:

```
update_loc() {
    // Attempt to login in through our User service
    this.busloc.update_loc(this.track_info).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log("Call provider in busloc.ts")
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Updating location failed")
    });
  }
```

In my provider (bus-loc.ts) I have:

```
  update_loc(track_info: any) {
    let seq = this.api.post('update_loc', track_info).share();

    seq.subscribe((res: any) => {
      // If the API returned a successful response, locations has been updated
      if (res.status == 'success') {
         console.log("Location updated succesfully")
      } 
    }, err => {
      console.error('ERROR', err);
    });

    return seq;
  }
```

In the BackEnd I have the following function:

```
//Actualizar ubicacion
function updateLoc(req,res){
    body = req.body;    
    TrackInfo.findOne({ where: { id: body.id } })
    .then(tr_info=>{
        if (!tr_info){
            return res.status(404).send ('No track_info found');
        }

        tr_info.update({
            is_active: body.is_active,
            lat: body.lat,
            lon: body.lon
        })
        console.log("Updated track info succesfully")
        return res.status(200); 
     

    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).send ('Server Error in updateLoc');
    });

}
```

Now I want to know how can I finish the API call, because I have read that the browser (Chrome in my case) can only execute six http requests, and since I call `update_loc()` several times in a row, the server gets blocked.
Please any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: the best way may be is to defer each call, in my opition you should not allow too much call to the API in the same time labs. Who or what call update_loc() ? May be that is the problem, you have too much usage of this function. Did you think about implementing socket for update your app? Instead of calling every ms the api

Comment: Update_loc() is called by an Observer, because I need to update in database the latitude and longitude every two seconds for example, but I test it even with ten seconds and the server stops executing after six requests anyway. That's why I think that it has to be involved with the api call.

Comment: What tech are you using on the backend ? looks like something is not closed in your backend. The post from http in angular doesn't stay open.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblizt in order to try your code ? hard to guess without something to test.

Comment: I am using Node.js for the BackEnd, with express to connect to PostgresQL database, I have updated the question with the code of the backend. Can you see any error? I do not know how to use stackblizt :c

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the last call with calling `unsubscribe`

```
  subscription: Subscription;
  update_loc() {
    // cancel last call
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    // Attempt to login in through our User service
    this.subscription = this.busloc.update_loc(this.track_info).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log("Call provider in busloc.ts")
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Updating location failed")
    });
  }
```

You can find more information here : https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Comment: The function update_loc() is called every 2 seconds by an Observer, then I want to execute it 100 or more times. I finish the Observer using unsubscribe(), but when the Observer calls update_loc() more than six times in a row, it stops executing the update query.

Comment: You can't bypass the maximum number of parallel http connection to the same domain for chrome :  
   http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top

Comment: Yes, thats why I want to know how to close the api call, then it wouldn't surpass the maximun number of http connection, am I right?

Comment: If you use unsubscribe the last call will be closed. Let me explain to you, if you are calling again update_loc() when the api call is not finish is not necessary to know the result because you will cal again the same api, so when you are `unsubscribe()` the last call, you ara closing the last api call. Make sense ?

Comment: But I want to close each api call after it is finished, so that I can execute update_loc() sequentially 100 or more times in a row. Closing only the last call does not resolve my problem, it just stops calling update_loc().

Comment: I think you don't understand how work a api call, when you are using a post request, is automaticly closed when is finished. Your problem is you are making too much call to the same api on a short time and chrome doesn't allow to do that.

Comment: take a look at socke.io and how to use it with node and angular. Socket allow to kept a stream 'open' between your app and a backend, with a socket you can emit data without limit of request from chrome. https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: Ok my friend, I will try it. Because I need to call it every two seconds. Thanks for your help.